# Limit of $\mathrm{erf}^{-1}(2^{-1/n})-\ln(-\log_2\beta) [\mathrm{erf}^{-1}(4^{-1/n})-\mathrm{erf}^{-1}((4/3)^{-1/n})]$

Tags: limits, special-functions

> I am looking for the limit, as $n\rightarrow\infty$, for the formula
>   $$ \mathrm{erf}^{-1}(2^{-1/n})-\frac{1}{c}\ln(-\log_2\beta)  [\mathrm{erf}^{-1}(4^{-1/n})-\mathrm{erf}^{-1}((4/3)^{-1/n})] \enspace, $$ in which $c=-\ln\log_4 4/3$ is a constant. $\beta$ is a
>   probability and $n\rightarrow\infty$.

I can (informally) get $O(\sqrt{\ln(1/\beta)\ln n})$ using the fact that the first term in the series expansion at $n\rightarrow\infty$ of $\mathrm{erf}^{-1}((4/x)^{-1/n})$ is $\sqrt{Z(x)-\ln(\pi Z(x)-\pi\ln(\pi))}/\sqrt{2}$ in which $Z(x)=\ln(2n^2/\ln ^2(4/x))$. However, I am looking for an exact limit or at least big $\Theta$ of it.

---

**Background (for the interested)**

This is a sort of a bound on the maximum deviation (measured by the infinity norm) a multinomial random variable can have from its mean with probability at most $\beta$.

I use the marginal random variables of the components of the multinomial vector, which are binomial random variables. Then, I use the normal approximation to the binomial distribution. The absolute value of the difference between each such random variable and its mean thus follows the half-normal distribution (this is where the erf function comes from). I then approximate the maximum of those i.i.d. $n$ half-normal random variables (they are i.i.d. at some limit) by a Gumbel distribution $\mathrm{M}+\mathrm{IQR} \cdot G$ whose median (M) and interquantile range (IQR) match the maximum of the i.i.d. half-normals (whose CDF is simply the product of their CDFs). Here $G=G(c^{-1}\ln\ln 2,c^{-1})$ is the Gumbel distribution whose median and interquantile range are 0 and 1, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

*I hope I have understood your question right*.

$\displaystyle \mathrm{erf}(x):=\frac{1}{\Gamma(1.5)}\int\limits_0^x e^{-t^2}dt$

$\displaystyle x=\mathrm{erf}(\mathrm{erf}^{-1}(x))=\frac{1}{\Gamma(1.5)}\int\limits_0^{\mathrm{erf}^{-1}(x)} e^{-t^2}dt$

$\displaystyle x^{-\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(1.5)}\int\limits_0^{\mathrm{erf}^{-1}(x^{-\frac{1}{n}})} e^{-t^2}dt \enspace$ , $\enspace x>0$

$n\to\infty$ : $\displaystyle \int\limits_0^{\mathrm{erf}^{-1}(1)} e^{-t^2}dt=\Gamma(1.5)$ which means that $\mathrm{erf}^{-1}(1)$ is well defined

Therefore one has

$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}(\mathrm{erf}^{-1}(2^{-1/n})-\frac{1}{c}\ln(-\log_2\beta)  [\mathrm{erf}^{-1}(4^{-1/n})-\mathrm{erf}^{-1}((4/3)^{-1/n})])= \mathrm{erf}^{-1}(1)$ .

Comment: Thank you for your answer (which is valuable since I got to learn a new way of thinking). However, I admit it was my fault that my question was not clear. I am interested in asymptotic behaviour at the limit, as expressed by functions simpler than erf (like ln for instance). An example is present in my question, but it is an upper bound (big Oh), while my question intended to ask about a tight bound (big Theta).

Comment: @M. Alaggan : Sorry that I haven't understood you well. At the moment I haven't enough time to think more about it. - I don't know if it helps here but sometimes it's useful to get an inversion function with: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem